# how do i turn off input method in a html input[type=text] box?

Tags: html

i am building a new input method as an extension of firefox & chrome. The problem is the default input method keep jumping out , so i want to turn the im off on default on the webpage.Is there a attribute in html set that? thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "input method"?

Answer (score 0):

To disable an input field just set the `disabled` attribute of the input tag.